# dotnet-trace in ASP.NET Core doesn't show any methods of controllers

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, profiling

I made a little ASP.NET Core applications to check out the `dotnet-trace` tool. It's an API with a single controller, returning some data from memory, nothing special.

The command I run is:

```
dotnet-trace collect --process-id 1 --format Speedscope --duration 00:00:01:00
```

While doing this I run a script sending requests to my controller during all the period of trace collecting. But after `dotnet-trace` finishes I can't see any useful information in the file I get. That's what I see:
[image]
So it doesn't show anything related to a controller or any of my other class, but instead of this I can see Program.Main and something called `UNMANAGED_CODE_TIME`.

Could you please help me understand what I did wrong and how can I get more detailed profile.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it seems like I need a big blackboard to write "I will always read a documentation before asking a question"...

If you're struggling with the same, try to use `n` and `p` keys to navigate between threads (`n` means `next`, and `p` means `previous`).

And on one of `.NET ThreadPool` threads I've found my methods:
[image]

I thought about removing the question, but now I think I'd better keep it here in case of anybody facing with the same situation.

Comment: OMG I was stumped by this for ages. Really terrible UX design. Thanks for not removing it!